# while installing git for android studio it shows this type of error, "internal error: CallspawnServer: Uexpected respose: $0"

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm trying to install git for android studio after installation it shows this type of error ***internal error: CallspawnServer: Uexpected respose: $0***
even after i installed latest version of both android studio 4.1.3 and git 2.31.1
whenever i'm trying to open adroid studio it gives me notification of **cannot run git, git is not installed**

while using adroid studio it redirect me again and again to installation window of git.

guys please suggest me i'm working on important project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SSH executable to your own native one:

AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Git -> SSH Executable and changed from Native to Built-in

Comment: Had the same problem on Windows after installing Clink, can confirm that removing Clink fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing SSH executable and uninstall the previous git version and reinstall it and finally it works.

First of all you can uninstall previous git version and reinstall new version of git, after that change SSH executable. Go through
AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Git -> SSH Executable and changed from Native to Built-in